# Undefined en el retorno de PHP al front con JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy intentando crear una validación de sesión con Jquery, AJAX, JSON y PHP. Tengo este código.

Esta es la función genérica que invoco en cada consulta, he modificado el código por que al parecer estaba haciendo yo el return dentro de la función de AJAX, he creado una variable para almacenar la respuesta y he regresado la variable, pero sigue sin funcionar, si hago el console.log dentro del `.done` lanza correctamente la respuesta, pero cuando salgo del AJAX, pierdo el valor de la variable.

```
  function ajaxConn(incomingUrl,incomingData)
  {
    var returnValue;
    $.ajax({
      url:'backend/'+incomingUrl,
      method:'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(incomingData),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }).done(function(response){
          returnValue = response.resp;
    });
    console.log(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
  }
```

Esta es la forma de invocación, en la data ya viene una serie de validaciones de los inputs:

```
var data = {user:user,pass:pass};
var answer = ajaxConn('core_files/startSession.php',data);
```

Todo este es mi código inicial en el PHP con lo que recibo la data:

```
require 'connection.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$user =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data["user"]);
$pass =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data["pass"]);
$response = array();
```

Después de una serie de consultas y cifrados dependiendo de la condición me regresa una Y para validación exitosa o una N para un fallo en el login que encapsulo en un array y lo paso a formato JSON y lo regreso.

```
$response["resp"] = 'N';
echo json_encode($response);
```

Si en el success de AJAX hago un `console.log(response.resp);` me regresa bien el caracter que arrojó el PHP. Pero si intento hacer un `console.log(answer)` fuera de la función de AJAX, en el lugar donde se invocó, me regresa **undefined**. Se supone que estoy dándole `return response.resp` Osea me tendría que regresar la letra.

Que me está fallando :(

Comment: Si quieres leer la respuesta como un JSON debes cambiar esto: `JSON.stringify(incomingData),`  por esto: `JSON.parse(incomingData),` ya que stringify toma tu JSON y lo convierte en una cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el ajax es una funcion asincrona, por lo tanto el valor que esta esperando `return response.resp` puede no devolverlo de forma inmediata y por eso el valor de tu respuesta puede ser indefinido.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es agregar al ajax el parametro `async : false` para que el transcurso del ajax y la consulta a tus datos sea de forma sincrona y espere terminar el proceso para seguir con el procedimiento.

Comment: Sigue igual con el async:false. No siento que sea un problema con la llamada de AJAX si no que es en el return de la función.

Comment: el asunto es que cuando haces el console.log dentro del success funciona bien? pero cuando esperas el retorno fuera falla?

Comment: Asi mero, cuando hago console.log en el success me da la letra que me está regresando el PHP, pero cuando le doy console.log a la variable que está cachando la respuesta de la invocación me regresa Undefined